# Calculate the area of the region $(x + y)^4 = ax^2y$

Tags: multiple-integral

Calculate the area of the region:
$$(x + y)^4 = ax^2y$$

Could you advise how to solving problems of this type?

Comment: @achillehui, yes, I see this. And what to do in this case?

Comment: By experimenting with Maple, for $a>0$ there seems to be a closed region in the first quadrant.

Comment: I've been mislead by the graph, there is actually a very tiny piece in the first quadrant (assume a = 1, it falls within $[0,0.1]^2$).  To compute area of that piece, change variable to polar coordinate $(x,y) = (r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ and then express $x$ in terms of $t = \tan\theta$. At the end, the area will be $\frac12 \int_0^{\pi/2} r^2 d\theta = \frac12 \int_0^\infty x^2 dt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the graph of $(x + y)^4 = ax^2y$ contains a closed loop I will assume that OP wants to find the area of the region bounded by the loop.

First, convert the equation to polar form using $x=r\cos\theta,\,y=r\sin\theta$ yielding

\begin{equation}
(r\cos\theta+r\sin\theta)^4=ar^2\cos^2\theta\cdot r\sin\theta
\end{equation}

This can be simplified and solved for $r$.

\begin{equation}
r=a\cdot\dfrac{\cos^2\theta\sin\theta}{(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^4}
\end{equation}

In polar form the loop in the first quadrant falls between $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Thus the area can be found by evaluating the integral

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{2}r^2\,d\theta=\frac{1}{2}a^2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{\cos^4\theta\sin^2\theta}{(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^8}d\theta
\end{equation}

If we let $F(\sin\theta,\cos\theta)=\dfrac{\cos^4\theta\sin^2\theta}{(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^8}$ we see that $F(\sin\theta,\cos\theta)= F(-\sin\theta,-\cos\theta)$. Thus we may make the substitution $t=\tan\theta,\,d\theta=\frac{dt}{1+t^2},\,\sin\theta=\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}},\,\cos\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$ to obtain, after simplification

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}a^2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{\cos^4\theta\sin^2\theta}{(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^4}d\theta=\frac{a^2}{2}\int_0^\infty \dfrac{t^2\,dt}{(1+t)^8}
\end{equation}

Partial fraction decomposition (using Wolfram) gives

\begin{equation}
\frac{a^2}{2}\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(t+1)^6}-\frac{2}{(t+1)^7}+\frac{1}{(t+1)^8}\right)dt\\
\end{equation}

Therefore the area of the region bounded by the loop is

\begin{equation}
\frac{a^2}{2}\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(t+1)^6}-\frac{2}{(t+1)^7}+\frac{1}{(t+1)^8}\right)dt=\frac{a^2}{210}\\
\end{equation}

The graph below is for $a=16$, the value for which the loop contains the point $(1,1)$.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but $r = a \frac{\cos^2\theta \sin\theta}{(\sin\theta + \cos\theta)^4} $

Comment: You are correct, it should be $\cos^2\theta$ instead of $\cos\theta$. I am going to withdraw the faulty solution until I can replace it with a correction. I will leave it up for a couple of hours so that you will see this message.

Comment: I see that this has been declared off-topic and put on hold. You need to change the instructions to say "Calculate the area of the region enclosed by the loop in quadrant I."

Comment: I still had an error but have corrected it.

Comment: Looking at your result for $a=16$, it is hard to believe that the area enclosed by the depicted loop is $256/105 \approx 2.44 $

Comment: @JeanMarie You are correct. The area is clearly less than $1.7$. I will try to find and correct the error.

Comment: Has the denominator to be 210, instead of 105, plainly (because of factor 1/2) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie You are correct. I had to work through from the beginning only to find out that I neglected to divide by $2$ at the very last step. Thanks for calling this to my attention.